# Apache web server - FTP host connection issue in LAN

Tags: apache2

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Web Server: Apache 2.2.22

Apache web server IP Address: 192.168.0.21

Virtual Host for website in Apache: 50000MySite001

Link to access website in LAN: 192.168.0.21/50000MySite001

User login details: ftpuser / password

Now I am trying to connect to this website (virtual host) using Dreamweaver from other PC in LAN. But it is not connecting with virtual host in Apache.

I am sure that I am missing something completely or doing something wrong and trying various things without luck. I only expect to get some hint on issue and I will do rest of things.

Thank you,

EDIT 01: 20 JUN 2016

- Apache web server IP Address: 192.168.0.21
- Other PC IP Address: 192.168.0.6

In my existing IIS Web Server, I am using below type of settings to make connection with website folder on web server in LAN and this is working fine.

- Access Type: FTP
- Host: 192.168.0.3 (IIS Web Server PC)
- Host Directory: 50000MySite001
- Login: ftpuser
- Password: password

I want to do same thing for my Apache web server so I can connect to project folder (virtual host located in Apache) and can work on it from other PC in LAN.

Comment: Are you attempting FTP access to a web server? You need to install and configure a separate FTP server on that machine, it doesn't work out-of-the-box.

Comment: @Jos, Currently I am not using any separate FTP server and I am not aware about it too. It will be very helpful if you just provide name or link for it and I will do rest of things by studying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no FTP server running on the web server machine. Dreamweaver assumes there is one, because it is used in many commercial hosting environments, where a FTP server is usually provided. On your local server, however, there isn't one running yet.

Install `vsftpd` (https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ftp-server.html) on the Apache machine. There are many other FTP servers, but this one is fairly easy to configure.

Comment: Ty. I successfully installed vsftpd by referring link you provided. Still I am unable to connect to virtual host on Apache Web Server... I guess I am unclear about few things. Please advise if possible... 1) How can I confirm that vsftpd is running under Apache Web Server? (currently I am managing Apache web server using webmin but I don't see any feature or option which indicates about FTP server... 2) Do I need to use same username/password that I use for my pc login? ... 3) Use of 'localhost' or local ip address (192.168.0.21) does make any difference?

Comment: If you use webmin and are already used to it, perhaps it would be better to remove vsftpd and install an FTP server that webmin can talk to, such as WU-FTPD.

Comment: I installed WU-FTPD and I can see it under webmin... but honestly I am not sure what settings I should keep so I just kept all default settings now... when I connect to virtual host 50000MySite001 from dreamweaver, it is connecting with with local folder I created with same name 50000MySite001 but not connecting with 50000MySite001 folder located under var/www/ folder ...  can you please advise on this issue? ty